# Formatting Date according to user profile settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each user of our application can have different format for Date and Time. I understand the date format is dependent on user's language and possibly time zone.

I guess I can try to run something like `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"` in ApplicationController. In this case Date.today.to_s would return the property formatted date. Will it be thread safe?

Another option I am looking at is to store profiles into `config/locales/en.yml` with different keys like `en_US`, `en_GB`, `en_...` and store locale name into the user's profile. In this case I will need to use I18n.localize to format the date. Is it possible to fall back to `en` if there is no key found in specific `en_US`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `Date::DATE_FORMATS` or `TIME::DATE_FORMATS`, you will need to take extra care to make their usage threadsafe, unfortunately. Shouldn't be too difficult to do, however.

AS for your second question, I believe you are concerned with locale fallbacks, and the [i18n gem has support for locale fallbacks](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb). This feature is easily enabled with:

```
I18n::Backend::Simple.include(I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```